# Gradle : UP-TO-DATE task

Tags: gradle, build, gradlew

I have task 'compileProfileObj' which mainly has to create a jar file.
Even in fresh environment setup, gradle logs outputs 'UP-TO-DATE' for this.

```
 task compileProfileObj(type: JavaCompile, dependsOn: [generateArtifacts]) {
    classpath = configurations.deployment
    source fileTree(
            dir: "${objDir}/app",
            includes: ['com/main/**'])
    destinationDir file("${proDir}/profileobjects-biz.jar")

    doLast {
        copy {
            from "${objDir}"
            include '*.xml'
            exclude 'server.xml'
            into "${proDir}/profileobjects-biz.jar/META-INF"
        }
        copy {
            from "${objDir}/profileobjects"
            into "${proDir}/profileobjects-biz.jar/META-INF"
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the gradle doesnot executed tasks in some cases if the tasks has successfully executed in previous build runs.
But in my case even in 1st run gradle doesn't execute this task and prints 'UP-TO-DATE'

Googling didnt help me much here.
Any suggestions in what scenarios this might happen will be really helpful.

Comment: Are there any Java source files in your source directories? If not, Gradle has nothing to do and therefor the task is marked UP-TO-DATE.

Comment: thanks! this is what the issue is.